# 2 inputs for Set-Annotation

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to use this command to set annotations on VMware virtual machines.

```
Set-Annotation -entity $vm -CustomAttribute "Owner" -Value "$owner"
```

I need the script to read 2 input files during the same loop.  One input for the entity name and one for the value.

If we make 2 text files,

```
file 1 = 
vm1
vm2
vm3

file 2 = 
john
bob
ken
```

I need the script to do:

```
Set-Annotation -entity vm1 -CustomAttribute "Owner" -Value "john"
```

then

```
Set-Annotation -entity vm2 -CustomAttribute "Owner" -Value "bob"
```

I've been able to get different loops to run, but nothing correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post some of the powershell loops you have tried, and an idea of what they actually produced so we can give more focused responses.

Comment: Read in both files and use an index loop that will reference the strings in each file array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
# Read VM names and owners into parallel arrays.
$vmNames = Get-Content 'file 1'
$owners = Get-Content 'file 2'

# Loop over the VM names with a pipeline and assign the corresponding owner
# by array index, maintained in variable $i.
$vmNames | % { $i = 0 } `
             { Set-Annotation -entity $_ -CustomAttribute "Owner" -Value $owners[$i++] }
```

You could streamline this by using `Get-Content 'file 1'` directly as the start of the pipeline, without the need to collect all lines in array variable `$vmNames` first.